# Can't view build errors from strings.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio, build

My app has a long strings.xml file, and when I add new strings or a new language translation of the file, I'm often getting a 'build failed' error message. I know this is caused by errors such as apostrophes without an escape backslash, and I see references to the lines with errors flash past in the build log before it stops and displays the message 'Failed to compile values file'. At this point I want to scroll back through the list of specific errors, but it has disappeared. How can I retrieve this list to view the errors? I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee. Thanks in advance.